# Emacs Org-mode ignores #+ATTR_LATEX

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I use beamer org-mode 8.2.10 to produce presentations.

In the following the width attribute (here 0.45) gets just ignored and replaced by 0.9

```
#+ATTR_LATEX: :width=0.45\linewidth
 [[file:/osx.png]]
```

which produces

```
\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{osx.png}
```

My work around is using this code instead:

```
#+latex:\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{osx.png}
```

which gives

```
\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{osx.png}
```

So what went wrong here in the first variation? Is that some bug or am I missing something fundamental?

Answer (score 5):

To fix this, use space (' ') instead of '='. For e.g.,

```
#+ATTR_LATEX: :width 0.45\linewidth
 [[file:/osx.png]]
```

Comment: Unfortunately did not work! :-(

Comment: Hmmm.. I'm using the latest ELPA version and it works fine there. Maybe [[file:./osx.png]]?

Comment: Works for `[[./foo.png]]` but not for `#+BEGIN_SRC ditaa`

Comment: `#+ATTR_LATEX: :width 0.45\linewidth [[file:./screen.jpg]]` work for me with the version of org mode downloaded today.